# Deleting a folder in a AVD

Tags: android, delete-file, android-virtual-device

I try to delete a folder with:

```
adb shell rmdir -f /storage/sdcard/myfolder
adb shell rmdir -r /storage/sdcard/myfolder
```

and I get the following error :

```
rmdir failed for -f, Read-only file system
```

How can I manage to delete that folder, without using java code. The folder is created by my app, so this is no system folder or the like.

*** UPDATE ***
deleting a file with
rm path/file works, but rmdir doesn't.

Comment: Dose rmdir has -f option as a flag? I cannot find the same.

Comment: f for force . -r for remove directory. Results in same errormessage.

Comment: I think I was not clear above. I am using ubuntu and I tried creating a directory and created a file within the same directory on ubuntu /home. But~/Desktop$ rmdir -r anu
rmdir: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'rmdir --help' for more information. Also  rmdir -f anu
rmdir: invalid option -- 'f'
Try 'rmdir --help' for more information. Since these commands are not working on linux then how would it work in emulator. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: As the message said "rmdir failed for -f, Read-only file system". The command is correct. The problem is not the syntax of the command, but that the filesystem is read only. How can I delete a folder with an ADB command or using Android Device Monitor ?

Comment: Hmm Yeah I figured that you are very correct. But still this option is not working on linux system. I will update as soon as I get to now something.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just updated the question. Deleting a file works fine, but howto delete a folder ?